# download csv from database error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database that I am downloading certain tables from like the staff table and an office table.

I have the button to download it to a CSV file so it can be opened into Excel easily.

This code works great when I'm on my local machine but the minute I upload it to a server I get warning messages that the header files have already been sent by another page and then the SQL statement dumps the requested information onto the page.

**So here is the code I'm using:**

**Button from main page:**

```
<form method="get" action="export_myStaff.php">
    <button type="submit" class="Mybutton">Download Staff Directory</button>
</form>
```

**export_myStaff.php**

```
require_once('../Connections/myconnections.php');

// Connect to the database
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database_testSite );
require_once('csv_myStaff.php');

$staff_table="myStaff_tbl";

exportMysqlToCsv($staff_table);
```

**csv_myStaff.php**

```
function exportMysqlToCsv($staff_table) {
    $csv_terminated = "\n";
    $csv_separator = ",";
    $csv_enclosed = '"';
    $csv_escaped = "\\";

    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM myStaff_tbl"

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $schema_insert = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++) {
            $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
                  stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
            $schema_insert .= $l;
            $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
    } // end for

    $out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
    $out .= $csv_terminated;

    // Format the data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $schema_insert = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++) {
            if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '') {
                if ($csv_enclosed == '') {
                    $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
                } else {
                    $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
                            $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
                }
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= '';
            }

            if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1) {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
            }
        } // end for

        $out .= $schema_insert;
        $out .= $csv_terminated;
    } // end while

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
//header("Content-type: text/csv");
//header("Content-type: application/csv");
$filename = $filename . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i", time());
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".csv");

//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $out;
exit;
}
```

Any ideas why it would work on my localhost but not on a server?

Comment: What php versions do you have on your localhost and on your server?

Comment: Are you implementing the files the same way, or are you using this code as a supplement and adding it to a website that already has an active MVC framework? Basically, you can only send headers if absolutely nothing has produced any output yet. No <!DOCTYPE>, echos, var_dumps, print_r, etc. You could look into using Ajax to request it, or have it generate the csv in a temporary folder on the server and use JavaScript to initialize the the download.

Comment: @Jason if he's not using mysqli or pdo i'm pretty sure there's no MVC framework.

Comment: Clearly not aware of the existence of [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) either; but if you're getting a message about headers already sent, then that message tells you exactly where to look for the output that is triggering the headers to be sent

Comment: sorry didn't see these earlier. @Jason I am using the same code on both the one that is throwing the error is supposed to be a pop up and it isn't making a new window it is just loading it in the same window. the localhost opens the new window but the live server doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it to work on the server using an entirely different script that was all on 1 page.
The link is here if anyone else has the same issue.

http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/

Answer (score 0):

This is almost always caused by something being echoed (it can even be a space) prior to the header call.

Remember that anything outside the  tags is also echoed so there must be no HTML or empty lines or blank spaces outside the PHP tags before your header file vis:

```
1 
2<?PHP
3//your code calling a header
4?>
```

will fail because the blank line is sent to the browser as output.

Also do a search of your file for echo, print, var_dump and any other output generating lines you may have left in for debugging.  These will cause the error too and of course may be hidden in conditional statements that are not executed every time.

```
echo ""; //does not upset your output but
echo " ";//does.
```

Neither can be seen on the screen.

If you can't find any other fault, please post the rest of your code.

As to how it is a problem on the server but not localhost, this depends on whether the code is truly identical, not uploaded with an extra line and whether the development environment has the same variables as the production environment.  I'd be reasonably confident that if you go back to basics as above, the problem will self-terminate.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no space anywhere that would be causing the issue and the code that I am using is posted above all of it.